# Excel: Multiple Levels of Protection

Tags: excel, vba

When protecting a sheet in Excel, the attached dialogue box appears, demonstrating the various possible protections that can be applied.

[image: Excel protection dialogue]

I have three types of cells in my workbook:

1. Cells that I don't want the user to be able to select (the vast majority).
2. Those that I want the user to be able to select, but not to edit (just one or two).
3. Those that I want the user to select and edit (a few).

However I don't seem to be able to protect cells differently; it seems that you pick the rules once, and they then apply to all protected cells. Is there a way around this? Perhaps using VBA?

Comment: Thanks @DonkeyKong but the ability to let users edit cells isn't the problem, it's the selection; I need them to only be able to select a handful of cells, and then only edit a subset of those.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps this helps you a little.
Try this;

1. Open your .xls(x) file
2. Open VBA editer with pressing Alt+F11
3. W-click a sheet name and paste below;

```vba
Sub unprotect()
    ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.unprotect
End Sub
Sub protect()
    ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.protect
End Sub
```

1. Back to your sheet window and press Alt+F8 and execute subs.

Comment: @kuhiy Thanks, but I don't understand what you're telling me to do.